# is MutableMap in kotlin/javascript or kotlin/native a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

As we know, A mutableMap object in kotlin/jvm is actually a LinkedHashMap object, but is it still always keep its order when iterating in kotlin/js or kotlin/native environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** not necessarily, not even on JVM. If you want to rely on LinkedHashMap's behaviour, use it explicitly.

---

**Long answer:**

> As we know, A mutableMap object in kotlin/jvm is actually a LinkedHashMap object

This is incorrect. `MutableMap` is an interface, and as such it can be implemented by any sort of implementation on any target (including JVM). It is most likely a bad idea to rely on the insertion order of a `MutableMap` *in general*, because iterating on it is not guaranteed by contract to be done in the same order as the insertion order. This is an implementation-dependent behaviour (not target-dependent).

On the JVM, you could use a `TreeMap` as a `MutableMap` too, and that wouldn't preserve insertion order:

```kotlin
val m: MutableMap<String, Int> = TreeMap()
m["a"] = 1
m["c"] = 3
m["b"] = 2
println(m) // prints {a=1, b=2, c=3}
```

Now, the `mutableMapOf()` top-level *function* currently returns a `LinkedHashMap` implementation on all platforms, but it's not part of its contract (it's not in the doc, and the return type is just `MutableMap`), so you should not rely on this because it's an implementation detail of the function.

`LinkedHashMap` is defined in the *common* part of the Kotlin stdlib, so most likely all platforms' actual implementations should respect the contract of `LinkedHashMap`. So if you really want to preserve insertion order, you should use `LinkedHashMap` explicitly in your code.